# Invert colors of expanding circles every 30 seconds

Tags: jquery, css

I have an animation with expanding `divs`, which can be seen here: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation/

I want to change colors every 30 seconds, i.e., if at the end of 30 seconds, the circles are dark blue, then to change to light blue and vice versa. The expanding divs animation keeps running infinitely.

This is what I have so far:

CSS:

```
.initial-div {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.position-div{
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: none;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation: expand 2500s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
    }

    100%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(100.0,100.0);
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Jquery:

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

        function makeDiv(divColor){
            var divsize = 1000;
            //$('body').css({'background-color':bgColor});
            console.log(1);
            $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass('initial-div').css({
                'background-color': divColor
            });

            var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();
            var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();

            $newdiv.addClass('position-div').css({
                'left':posx+'px',
                'top':posy+'px'
            }).appendTo( 'body' ).addClass('animate').css({'display':'block'}).one(animationEnd,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

 $(document).ready(function(){
        var flag=0;
            function changeColors(){
                console.log(2);
                setInterval(change(),30000);
            }

            function change(){
                console.log(3);
                if (flag == 0){
                    console.log(31);
                    color='#11256c';
                    flag=1;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(32);
                    color='#24ccdf';
                    flag=0;
                }
                setInterval(function(){makeDiv(color)},2000);
            }
            changeColors();

        });
```

Because the makeDiv function is running infinitely, the setInterval function invoking change() doesn't get called for a second time and the colors do not invert. Is there any way to fix this problem? Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using jQuery already, you can do this by attaching **[jQuery UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/)** so that you may use its **[jQuery animate](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)** functions. I think that there is no way to update the color of an object with plain jQuery functionality.

In order for You to make those circles animate their background property, you will need to set the interval from `3000` to `30000` ms.

```js
var indexNumber = 0;

function colorChange() {
    var colors = ["#FF1493", "#DC143C", "#7FFF00", "#FF69B4"];
    $('.circle').animate({
        'background-color': colors[indexNumber]
    }, 3000);
}

setInterval(function () {
    colorChange()
    indexNumber++
    if (indexNumber == 4) {
        indexNumber = 0
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: this was a valuable hint, but its not quite holding together with my code - the colors are still not changing. Could you help me a bit more with this?

Comment: It is as simple as copy-pasting the code I have provided, simply change the classes and colors etc. Have you added my snippets to your code, and have you linked the scripts that are specified in my html snippet?